# How to get mpld3 to display the same figure as matplotlib without it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpld3

I have an existing system using matplotlib that just saves the figure to a .png file:

```
rootfilename = '%d.png' % t
fyle = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/' + rootfilename
fig.savefig(fyle)
context = {'ourimg' : rootfilename}
return render(request, 'sensors/img.html', context)
```

That works to show the graph I am expecting:
[image: The image with matplotlib: looks fine]

But I tried using mpld3:

```
g = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
return HttpResponse(g)
```

... and it's not even close. I get the y ticks correct (but smaller) but none of the graphs I see on the same figure saved to a file and displayed the other way.

I must be missing something; help please!

Comment: What is the meaning of the sentence "None of the graphs I see on the same figure saved to a file and displayed the other way"? Without [mcve] it's anyways hard to know what's wrong. But in general consider that `mpld3`'s support for matplotlib is not complete.

Comment: The display just shows the outline: y ticks and legend and  xticks (dates messed up but I've seen a post on how to fix that) ... and no data graphs displayed at all.

Comment: If mpld3 doesn't yet fully support matplotlib; what's the shortest path to get this done? A REST service for a duplicate of the data to be grabbed by Javascript? Or something else that works with matplotlib?